# How to fix input dynamic category select dropdown with ajax/json in vuejs

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js

I'm developing a category selection template with pass in the previous selection.
But the select Only works on "on first loading" if I change the select so I get behavior error. (this unselect the parent)

I need a "light".

This is the link of project
https://zimeonline.com.br

I try changer the object vue data() in  each ajax in my components

```
<template>
    <div>
        <select @change="category()" v-model="selectedId" v-bind:key="option[0].id"  v-for="option in options" class="browser-default custom-select">
          <option  v-bind:value="op.id" v-bind:selected="op.selected==1" v-bind:key="op.id" v-for="op in option">{{op.name}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        name: "ProductFormCategory",
        data() {
            return {
                options: {},
                selectedId:''
            }
        },
        created() {
            let vm = this;
            vm.category();
        },
        methods: {
            async category() {
                let vm = this;
                await vm.$http.get('category/'+vm.selectedId).then(function (response) {
                    vm.options = response.data;
                }).catch(function () {
                });
               vm.$forceUpdate();
            },
        }
    }
</script>

<style scoped>
    .browser-default{
        margin-bottom: 10px !important;
    }
</style>
```

```
this URL list ALL FATHER categorys
https://api.zimeonline.com.br/api/category
```

```
this URL list ALL CHILDREN categorys
https://api.zimeonline.com.br/api/category/some_id(from father category)
```

```
exemple: https://api.zimeonline.com.br/api/category/5

Then 5 is ID from  https://api.zimeonline.com.br/api/category
```

here an exemple of the atual code  select
https://zimeonline.com.br  (a litle slow in the fist time)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Solution for category basead from parent id with select input  option sub-menu
<script>
export default {
    name: "ProductFormCategory",
    props:{
      setCategoryId:String
    },
    data() {
        return {
            options: {},
            categoryId: ''
        }
    },
    created() {
        let vm = this;
        vm.categoryId = vm.setCategoryId || ('');
        vm.category();
    },
    methods: {
        async category(event) {
            let vm = this;
            if (event) {
               vm.categoryId = (event.target.value);
            }
            await vm.$http.get('category/' + vm.categoryId).then(function (response) {
                vm.options = response.data;
            }).catch(function () {
            });
        },
    }
}
```

```
<template>
<div>
    <select
            @change="category($event)"
            v-bind:key="option[0].id"
            v-for="option in options"
            class="browser-default custom-select">
        <option value="">Selecione uma categoria</option>
        <option
                v-bind:value="op.id"
                v-bind:selected="op.selected==1"
                v-bind:key="op.id"
                v-for="op in option">
                {{op.name}}
        </option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I understand your questions. But I see some problems in your code:

- Why did you put a `v-for` in both select and option?
- In the first loop, you bind a key to `option[0]` instead of `options[0]` or `option`

Also a tip: You could use `vm.$set` to make reactive variables